# Unexpected symbol near '.'

Tags: function, variables, lua

I tried changing to ansi, but it didn't work. 
it is in line 5: unexpected symbol near '.'

```
side =  { 0, Arena.width }

function Update()
    local chasingbullet = CreateProjectile('bullet', myTable[ math.random( #myTable )], math.random(0, Arena.height))
    local chasingbullet.SetVar('speed', 0)
    local dist = Player.x - chasingbullet.x
    local speed = chasingbullet.GetVar('xspeed') / 2 + xdifference / 100
    chasingbullet.Move(speed, 0)
    chasingbullet.SetVar('speed', speed)
end
```

every place i search, don't help me and say that the code is normal

Comment: It's a Syntax / Parsing Error: so, *which line* and *which part of the line*? After *identifying what the error message is referring to*, **why does the error *make sense***? Hint: something about `local` and what variables are what variables are not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`local chasingbullet.SetVar('speed', 0)` has a syntax error. `local` can only be followed by a variable name or list of names and an optional equals sign and list of expressions; for example:

```
local a
local a = 1
local a, b
local a, b = 1, 2
local a, b = 1
```

So the parser is okay with `local chasingbullet`, but then it sees the dot (`.`) and complains because a dot is not allowed there. To fix the error, just remove `local`: `chasingbullet.SetVar('speed', 0)`.